# Keepass auto-type perform auto-type {USERNAME}{ENTER}

Tags: keepass

I run out of ideas about where to look for help.

My problem is that my company migrated to a new way to ship us Software which also resulted in a new keepass installation.
Previously I always used the perform auto-typ menu entries
[image]

But now this Menu entry is not present and I could not find any info about this menu entry.
It now looks like this:
[image]

Does anybody know about this, or now in which version this was implemented...

Also if I should ask this question on some other StackExchange Site please direct me to it.

Answer (score 1):

This feature can be enabled via the Setting `Tools > Options > Interface > "Show additional auto-type menu commands"`